# "macOS Sierra Update" could not be verified

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I tried updating my new MBP from macOS Sierra 10.12 to 10.12.3 using the App Store. I can see that the download of the update file finishes in App Store. I also get the prompt to restart. The machine restarts after approving it and it starts the update process. The update suddenly stops and shows an error message:

> **"macOS Sierra Update" could not be verified.**
>   You can try updating again in the App Store after restarting.

I took a screenshot.

[image: macOS Sierra Update could not be verified]

After pressing Restart, the machine restarts and macOS Sierra version is still 10.12. I tried several times to update again using the App Store but it gets stuck with the same issue. Any hints how to complete the update to 10.12.3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to update by using the [combo updater](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1905?locale=en_US) for 10.12.3. The DMG file can be downloaded outside of the App Store and I can explicitly know that the file is good because it verifies itself.

Comment: Did you get mac os sierra 10.12.5 updates from AppStore as well, or again the combo updater i.e. https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1918?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US  ??

Comment: Nope, it worked seamlessly at least for me by 10.12.5.